# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method share on channel plugins.flutter.io/share) in release mode

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using Flutter SDK: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0" (without null safety) for my project. While all the plugins run in debug mode, I encounter the MissingPluginException only in release mode. The same error occurs even when the released version targets the Android platform.

```
[+6213 ms] E/flutter (15858): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found
for method share on channel plugins.flutter.io/share)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter (15858): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156)
[        ] E/flutter (15858): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter (15858):
```

How do I make these plugins work in release mode?

Comment: Please add full log